# use activerecord to retrieve virtual attributes when using select() with includes() and where()

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having trouble retrieving virtual attributes when making database queries.  The following works as expected:

```
s = Story.includes(:scenes).select("stories.*, 3 as testval")
s.first.title
=> "My Story"
s.first.testval
=> 3
```

But when I put in a where clause, it stops working:

```
s = Story.includes(:scenes).select("stories.*, 3 as testval").where("scenes.id < ?",1000).references(:scenes)
s.first.title
=> "My Story"
s.first.testval
NoMethodError: undefined method `testval' for #<Story:0x007fcd6b93eb68>
```

I'm guessing the issue is that ActiveRecord doesn't know that 'testval' should belong to 'stories' instead of 'scenes', but I'm not sure.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but you can't do a custom select and eager load as references/eager_load overrides the select with a bunch of `t%d_r%d`.

You'll need to do approach with a different ActiveRecord strategy if you need virtual attributes.